# WPF binding 2 properties from 1 List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

So what i am trying to accomplish is that i am trying to bind 2 properties from 1 list to 2 different `ComboBoxes`.

code:

```
combobox1.DataContext = class.repository;
combobox2.DataContext = class.repository;
```

and in xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Password}"/>
```

example - repository[0] = "NAME1"

The result i get is when i open `ComboBox` looks like:

1 item - N

2 item - A

3 item - M
and so on..

and result i want is

1 item = NAME1

2 item = NAME2
 ...

Thanks for replies.

Comment: is class.repository a list?? you need to bind combobox's datacontext to a list to get the desired results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `repository` is a `string[]`, you should bind the `ItemsSource` to the `DataContext` itself:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

If repository is an `IEnumerable<YourClass>` where `YourClass` is a type with a `Name` and a `Password` property, you should also set the `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Password"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use DisplayMemberPath property of the ComboBox to specify you want to see the value of propery "Name".

Comment: But a string has no "Name" property.

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i needed.. Helped me a lot! :)